# Go regex find substring

Tags: regex, go

I have a string:

```
s := "root 1 12345 /root/pathtomyfolder/jdk/jdk.1.8.0.25 org.catalina.startup"
```

I need to grep the version number to a string

Tried,

```
var re = regexp.MustCompile(`jdk.*`)
func main() {
matches := re.FindStringSubmatch(s)
fmt.Printf ("%q", matches)
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! "Please help" isn't much of a question. You should show what you have tried, and what didn't work. Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You probably want to look at [regexp](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/) for this.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify capturing groups to extract submatches, as described in the [package overview](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#pkg-overview):

> If 'Submatch' is present, the return value is a slice identifying the
>   successive submatches of the expression. Submatches are matches of
>   parenthesized subexpressions (also known as capturing groups) within
>   the regular expression, numbered from left to right in order of
>   opening parenthesis. Submatch 0 is the match of the entire expression,
>   submatch 1 the match of the first parenthesized subexpression, and so
>   on.

Something along the lines of the following:

```
func main() {
    var re = regexp.MustCompile(`jdk\.([^ ]+)`)
    s := "root 1 12345 /root/pathtomyfolder/jdk/jdk.1.8.0.25 org.catalina.startup"
    matches := re.FindStringSubmatch(s)
    fmt.Printf("%s", matches[1])
    // Prints: 1.8.0.25
}
```

You'll of course want to check whether there actually is a submatch, or `matches[1]` will panic.

Comment: I need to get the version details in a string. Not able to get that

Comment: `matches[1]` in my answer is a string containing `1.8.0.25`. As far as I can tell, this is exactly what you need.

Comment: Might want to try it out on https://regex-golang.appspot.com/assets/html/index.html to see the result?

Answer (score 0):

if you need the value in a string variable to be used / manipulated elsewhere, you could add the following in the given example Marc gave:

```
a := fmt.Sprintf("%s", matches[1])
```